# Extra CRLF in Http transfer encoding chunked (http protocol violation)

Tags: java, c++, http, tomcat

Hi I am using [happyhttp library](http://scumways.com/happyhttp/happyhttp.html) to do http post and get. It is working fine except when data from server is coming with transfer encoding chunked. As given in [chunked encoding wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) "\r\n" comes with hex value of chunked data and "\r\n\r\n" only comes when chunked left is 0. 
But in my case "\r\n\r\n" is coming with every chunked data. because of this I am getting extra clrf in my content. Is it not a protocol violation? what can be done about this?

server is tomcat 6.0. server is sending data using java bytestream.

Comment: Can you post your code? Also, which language are you using - C++ or Java? I'm guessing you're not writing JNI calls here, right?

Comment: i am using happyhttp at client side c++(link given above)